# PHP won't echo after a query fetch

Tags: php, echo

I have written up some code to take a upc entry from a text box and upon submit will pass the "upc" to the query code.

My problem is, none of my echos will post to my page. I can get them to post in CLI, but not on my web browser. If I put in test echos before the fetch line of the query they will echo to the page, but anything after the query will not. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    //setup
    require_once('Factual.php');
    $factual = new Factual("mykeyhere","myotherkeyhere");
    $upc = $_GET["upc"];
    $query = new FactualQuery;
    $query->search($upc);
    $res = $factual->fetch("products", $query);
    $data = $res->getData();
    //print_r($res->getData());
    $item = $data[1];
    $itemAvgPrice = $item['avg_price'];
    $itemBrand = $item['brand'];
    $itemCategory = $item['category'];
    $itemEan13 = $item['ean13'];
    $itemFactualID = $item['factual_id'];
    $itemImage = $item['image_urls'][0];
    $itemSize = $item['size'][0];
    $itemUPC = $item['upc'];


    echo "Average Price: " . $itemAvgPrice;
    echo "\nBrand: " . $itemBrand;
    echo "\nCategory: " . $itemCategory;
    echo "\nEan13: " . $itemEan13;
    echo "\nFactual ID: " . $itemFactualID;
    echo "\nImage URL: " . $itemImage;
    echo "\nSize: " . $itemSize;
    echo "\nUPC: " . $itemUPC;

     ?>
```

Comment: So there might be some exception on that fetch line?

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP log files?

Comment: I forgot about error reporting in PHP since I don't use it much. Here is what I got. "Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER'"

Comment: I see, the code called for use by the fetch query in the Factual.php page has an error relating to the initialization of Curl. Thanks for sparking the ol' noggin, guys.